# Experiencing badimageformatexception while trying to connect Oracle Db in C# webdriver framework

Tags: c#, oracle, oledbconnection

```
 public static void Main()

        {
            Init();
            Console.WriteLine("Init method call Over");
            Console.WriteLine("DB connectivity starts");
            databaseConnectivity();
            Console.WriteLine("DB connectivity method over");
            TestMethod1();
            Console.WriteLine("TestMethod method call Over");
            CleanUp();
        }
```

For databaseConnectivity, we have

```
public static void databaseConnectivity()
        {
            OracleConnection con;

            try
            {
                //java.sql.DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver());

                Console.WriteLine("inside DB connectivity method");
                con = new OracleConnection();
                if (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["testSiteURL"].Equals( "***************************************************************"))
                {
                    con.ConnectionString = "User Id=**;Password=**;Data Source=**";
                }
                else
                {
                    con.ConnectionString = "User Id=**;Password=**;Data Source=**";
                }
                //con = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, "**", "**");
                con.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Connected to Oracle" + con.ServerVersion);

                //con.Close();
                //con.Dispose(); 

            }
            //con.setAutoCommit(false);
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Write("Connection failed:" + e.Message);
            }
        }
```

But on calling `databaseConnectivity()`, it shows

> badimageformatexception exception unhanded

.We already added `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` as references and also installed `ODAC121012_x64` for Oracle Data Access.

issue description says:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.3.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its
>   dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect
>   format.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Platform target setting in Project Properties :

Project Properties -> Build -> Platform Target.If it is x86 then change it to x64..

Also check the warnings when you have built the solution.It should certainly have a warning telling you that you are going to receive this kind of error.

I got this error last week while migrating my project from windows xp to windows 7.